# Too many open files exception on AwS machine with high configuration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nginx, server

My sincere apologies if the question is stupid but I am a novice here (front end developer, recently working on backend).

I have my app running on Amazon aws machine. What I want is to efficiently utilize my resources so that more requests are served.

I am running a Java vertx server that serves GET and websocket request. I have created three instances of this server running on different port and balanced the load using nginx.

My aws resource is pretty much

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   100G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   100G  0 part /
```

My soft limit is unlimited

```
ulimit -S
unlimited
```

My hard limit is unlimited

```
ulimit -H
unlimited
```

I am checking the total number of opened files as

```
sudo lsof -Fn -u root| wc -l
13397
```

Why am i getting this exception

> java.io.IOException: Too many open files

My ulimit -a is

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128305
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 700000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 128305
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

What is the best way to check the number of available files and also the number of files that are used. And how should I use the resources in such a way that I can make large number of connections.

Please let me know.

Comment: Can you post the output of: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` and `ulimit -a`

Comment: cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max is 300000

Comment: @Behe please check, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your hard limit and soft limit is set properly. But you are getting this error because the vertx is not able to utilize the full ulimits that you have set.

Check what is the maximum limit, your vertx server can use by:

cat /proc/PID/limits

```
 Max open files    700000      700000    files
```

is the line that tells you.

If you have set the soft limit high but still this value comes low then there is something in the app (like the init files) that is changing the soft limit.

So you can find that init script and simply change the soft limit there. It will fix your problem.

https://underyx.me/2015/05/18/raising-the-maximum-number-of-file-descriptors

Answer (score 2):

I believe you check the wrong limit.

From `man ulimit`

> If no option is given, then **-f** is assumed.

This means `ulimit -S` returns the same as `ulimit -S -f`, respective `ulimit -H` and `ulimit -H -f`.

The option `-f` means

```
The maximum size of files written by the shell and its children
```

The exception `java.io.IOException: Too many open files` mention `too many open files`. Therefore you need to check the `The maximum number of open file descriptors`.

```
# as root
$ ulimit -S -n
1024
$ ulimit -S -n 2048
2048
```

On CentOS 7 `man ulimit` mention for option `-n`

> -n     The maximum number of open file descriptors (most systems do not allow this value to be set)

On some system you might not be able to change it.

Comment: I checked as u said, the soft limit is still 'unlimited' and hard limit is 700000.

Comment: @CuriousMind Sorry. I had a typo in my post. It had to be `ulimit -S -n` instead of `ulimit -S`. That's the reason why you got `unlimited` (it's for max. size of files written, as stated already). You cannot have a larger soft limit then for the hard limit. But why your application need more then 700.000 open files at the same time?

Comment: ulimit -S -n is 700000. My application receives large number of request. And I am getting lot of 'Too many files' opened exception.

Comment: @CuriousMind Maybe it's worth to investigate why your application needs for each request an open file. To find a list of files open by an application you could use the `lsof` tool.